# Error while importing localization

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I downloaded the `localization` package in Anaconda. But when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>     import localization   File "~\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\localization\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>     
from geoProject import * 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geoProject'
```

I do not know what to do, can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

"geoProject", must be your project name, not the name of the module you are trying to input.

Try:

```
from your module import *
```

or just

```
import yourmodule
```

It works if your module is in current directory. Unless you should write the full path to your module